# select 1 column can match with many columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the 1 table (tblcsv) in database that have data as below:

```
fieldA  fiel B
aaaa    1

aaaa    2

aaaa    4

a       1

aaaa    2

a       3

bbbb    4

b       3

bbbb    4

b       3
```

**What I need to display:**

```
aaaa        1
            2
            4
            2
a           1
            3
bbbb        4
            4
b           3
            3
```

I really do not know how to write mysql for query it from database to display what I need.Anyone help me please, Thanks.

Comment: you can get the data by using order by on "fieldA  " and then use PHP to format your data

Comment: .. oreder by fieldA, fieldB - you will have to do the rest with php

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT fieldA, fieldB 
  FROM tblcsv 
  order by feildA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select fieldA , fiel B from table 
order by fieldA ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but if I do like this it will loop all record of fieldA that has the same name like `aaaa aaaa` for many time.I want it display one time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)**

```
SELECT fieldA, GROUP_CONCAT(fieldB) 
FROM    tblcsv
```